# Python - Class and function

Tags: python, class, function, object

Doing a class and finished with the rest less this one. Any guidance is appreciated. I have derived part of the question where I am stuck with to keep it short. I have also attached my working.  Question as follows:

> Create a class with 1 variable in it holding its own properties.
>   Provide the following 3 methods:
>
> getvariable1() - use return key tp return value of property 1
>
> setvariable1() - This should allow new value to be specified for property 1 - additional parameter needed to accept input.
>
> printerfun() - to print values of the variables for the object.
>
> Create your own object of the class and call get & set methods for the object created. Use printerfun() method to check if the codes works.

My working:

```
class animal:
    horns = 2

    def printerfun(self):
        print getHorns() 

    def getHorns(self): #don't get where I should call this
        return self.horns

    def setHorns(horns): 
        self.horns = horns

animal_1 = animal()

F1 = raw_input('Please enter number of horns: ')
setHorns(F1)
```

Comment: Kesh, welcome to StackOverflow and to programming in Python. We're happy to help answer questions here, and to help beginners with their code. However, we expect that when people ask a question that they have a specific problem that they want solved. What you have asked for is a general critique of your code. If you want good help, I would post a new question (with the code you've pasted here) and say what it is you expect to happen when you run your code, what is actually happening when you run it, and why you're confused.

Comment: @Wilduck -- Why are you advising OP to post a new question when this one can be edited to make it suitable?

Comment: @mgilson A few reasons, really. For one, there are already answers to this question as asked; second, it has already accrued downvotes; third, new users seem to have a hard time understanding editing their question; fourth, I've seen that advice given before. All that being said, if I'm breaking some SO rule/custom, I'd be open to being corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but anyway...

You should write a `__init__` member function to create the initial member variables:

```
class animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.horns = 2
```

Your code creates a *class variable*, not a normal member variable.

Then change the horns with:

```
animal_1.setHorns(F1)
```

Your code doesn't say which animal you want to change the variable to.

Comment: There are some other problems with the code as well. For example, `setHorns` should take `self` as its first parameter